# When do I need a default constructor?

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor, default

```
class Test
{
private :
    int i;
public:
    Test(int m)
    {
      i = m;
    }
    void restart(int k)
    {
        Test(k);
    }
};
```

However, the compiler (VS17) send me an error saying that "no default constructor exists for class Test", but I don't think I need a default constructor since all functions in this class need a int type argument.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. That code doesn't require a default constructor so the issue likely lies elsewhere. What are you trying to do in `restart`? Why not just simply `i = k;`

Comment: Perhaps what you intended inside `restart()` was:  `Test t(k);` ?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I guess they were trying to "call the constructor" like a normal function, hoping to re-execute the statements in the constructor body

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In

```
class Test {
// ...
    void restart(int k)
    {
        Test(k);
    }
};
```

the statement `Test(k);` declares a variable of type `Test` named `k`. This variable `k` is initialized by calling the default constructor which doesn't exist.

> I don't think I need a default constructor since all functions in this class need a int type argument.

That is neither a reason for nor against a `class` having/needing a default constructor or not.

If what you want is to set the value of `Test::i` inside `Test::reset()` then just do so:

```
class Test
{
private:    
    int i;

public:    
    Test(int m) : i{ m }  // you should use initializer lists instead of 
    {}                    // assignments in the constructors body.

    void restart(int k) { i = k; }
};
```

Comment: Can I call the constructor of a class in its member function to change the value of member variable of the object of that class?

Comment: @CharlieLee Sort of. You could do `*this = Test(k);`